# Unanswered tab shows me having modified questions I didn't even know existed

Tags: support

On the main site, I was in the Unanswered section, votes tab, and while scrolling saw this in the listing:

[image]

I don't think I've ever seen seen those two questions, not that it matters because the actual questions show I haven't touched them, either:  [1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14251/setting-up-a-personal-domain-name)   [2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9880/looking-for-windows-hosting-reseller-provider-with-decent-reputation)   Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see your name when I go to those questions now, and the first one shouldn't even be in the unanswered section as it has one upvoted answer (unless it was upvoted very recently). If it is a bug it may be transitory.

Comment: @paulmorris That might've been unclear. If you go *to* the questions, I'm not shown as having edited(because I didn't). The screenshot is of the Unanswered listing screen, where I do still see this behavior. They've since rearranged, but the hosting one should show up on the fifth page(at 50  per page). Edited.

Comment: Yes, I can see the hosting one showing up as in your screenshot. Definitely reproducible then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edited deleted answers on those pages (related to a spammer posting "Arvixe" affiliate links) and the spammer's account - along with those "answers" - has since been deleted.

Comment: Oh, okay. I wasn't even paying attention to the actual content then, just scrubbing the affiliate stuff. Forgot the account was eventually nuked.